# How to access form element with javascript without using element's id

Tags: javascript, html, dom, client-side

I want to access form elements by using javascript. The form is generated dynamically so the name, id of the form and the elements are variable. I want to get the id value of a `textarea` inside it  by providing the name of the form, which is generated by a different script.

For instance:

```
<form method=post name=form33>
    <textarea id=466 cols=50 rows=5></textarea>
    <input name=submit33 onclick=postCmnt(33) value=Post type=button>
</form>
```

and I have the name of the form name "form33" and I need its `textarea` id that is 466 as output...

### Javascript Generating The Form:

```
function openComment(id, msgid, div) {
    var div = document.getElementById(div);
    div.innerHTML = "<form method=post name=form"+id+">
        <textarea id="+msgid+" cols=50 rows=5></textarea>
        <input name=submit"+id+" onclick=postCmnt("+id+") value=Post type=button>
        </form>"
}
```

## Javascript that need to access the form

Here is my attempt to access the `id` name of `textarea` by providing form name.

```
function postCmnt(id){
    var msgid=document.forms["form"+id].elements[0].id.value;//the text area's id
    var msg=document.getElementById(msgid).value;//value of text area
    //rest scripts goes here        
}
```

Information:

1. Form is not static generated by call to the function openComment()
2. predicting number of form in a page is not possible as it depends upon user input .Though the textarea is the 1st element of the form .

Comment: is the form id static

Comment: `document.querySelector('[name="form"]')` ?

Comment: the form and is attributes are not static its generated by the first javascript function when called , there might be more than one form in the document .

Comment: not sure what your issue is exactly but from what you posted you need to at least remove the "text" from the getElementById("text"+msgid) since the word text does not apear in the id of the textboxes.

Comment: @EyalAlsheich: Yes you are right ,made this mistake when I was forming the question from my project .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hidden field that contains the msgid:

Javascript Generating The Form:

```
function openComment(id,msgid,div){
    var div = document.getElementById(div);
    div.innerHTML="<form method=post name=form"+id+">
        <input type='hidden' id='theid"+id+"' value='"+msgid+"'>
        <textarea id="+msgid+" cols=50 rows=5></textarea>
        <input name=submit"+id+" onclick=postCmnt("+id+") value=Post type=button>
        </form>"
}
```

and then just get the value directly:

```
function postCmnt(id){
    var msgid=document.getElementById("theid"+id).value;//the text area's id
    var msg=document.getElementById(msgid).value;//value of text area
    //rest scripts goes here        
}
```

Comment: hmm thats a way for doing exactly what I want . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one form in the documents, you can do

```
   document.forms[0]
```

Comment: Forms in the page is more than one and number of the form is variable changes upon user input.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you can use

```
 document.getElementById("teller")[i]
```

to access the i-th field of the form with id "teller".

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uUnYw/12/)

Comment: Thanks .So if the name of the for is "x" say and textarea is first element so I can access it like this document.forms["x"][0] ? right ?

Comment: but sadly its returning some error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: No you need to use the form's number.If it's the first from in the document, then it's forms[0], so the j-th element of the i-th form will be referred to as forms[i][j]

Comment: but its variable in a page ! and only thing I know can get is the name/id of the form